# Specify center of rotation in Sketch

Tags: sketch-app

Is there a way to specify the center of rotation in Sketch?
Normally it simply rotates the object around its center.
If there is no native way maybe it's possible to write a plugin!?

Comment: You can always do what the matrix manipulations behind the scenes do rotate then reposition.

Answer (score 7):

As spiral said, the functionality was added in version 3.2. To use it, you will need to select the layer you want to rotate and either click the Rotate tool in the toolbar or select `Layers > Transform > Rotate Layer`.

Once you are in Rotate mode, you will see a small target that you can reposition to change the center of rotation.

Comment: I wish it would save the location of that point, so you could just modify the rotate value in the inspector subsequently.

Answer (score 1):

Currently (v3.0.4) that's not possible

Answer (score 1):

This functionality was added in [Sketch 3.2](http://bohemiancoding.com/sketch/support/updates/sketch-3.2/)